# Restore previous file selection in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

Right now I'm not sure if I used to use this feature in Total Commander of Volkov Commander. I cannot find anything like that in Total Commander. Does it exist there?

I very carefully **selected a few files** from a directory and instead of moving them I only copied them. So I need to **selected them again** and move...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

/ on the numpad "restores" last selection. Extremely useful in combination with numpad * (inverse selection)

Comment: Just to elaborate, this can also be found via the menu: `Mark > Restore Selection`